# What is causing error in first function which seemingly looks similar to second function?

Tags: c++11, syntax

Below functions are giving different results. What's the supposed difference between them that is causing different outputs. e.g n=30 and k=417219134 are giving output 0 and 1 respectively.

Function 1(Wrong):

```
int kthGrammar(int n, int k) {
if (n==1){
    return 0;
}
int parent_node = kthGrammar(n-1, ceil(float(k)/2));
int isKodd = k%2;
if (isKodd){
    return parent_node;}
else{
    return parent_node==0?1:0;}
}
```

Function 2(Right):

```
int kthGrammar(int n, int k){
if (n==1){
    return 0;
}
int isKodd = k%2;
if (isKodd){
    return kthGrammar(n-1, (k+1)/2);}
else{
    return (kthGrammar(n-1, k/2)==0?1:0);}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `int` `417219134` can't be perfectly represented by a `float`.

```
float  f = 417219134;
double d = 417219134;

std::cout << std::fixed
          << f << '\n'   // 417219136.000000
          << d << '\n';  // 417219134.000000
```

This explains why `ceil(float(k)/2)` returns a number that is +1 off from the expected when `k = 417219134`.

I'd convert to `double` in the function instead:

```
int parent_node = kthGrammar(n-1, ceil(k / 2.));
```